# How to remove ad countdown timer in google-ima SDK?

Tags: javascript, ads, video.js, google-ima

I'm using video.js and videojs-ima plugin in order to create ad pre-rolls on videos, however; Google's Ads SDK creates an ad countdown timer through the `videoAdUi` and it appends it through a `iframe` which means I cannot affect or change the styles within the iframe.

I also found [this](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/countdown-timer), but obviously I'm trying to achieve the opposite.

Here's a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZpUB.jpg) of my problem.

I'm trying to get rid of the `Ad: (00:14)` and keep the one I already have. Like I've already mentioned, I followed the trail to figure out it was in a iframe with the class of `videoAdUiAttribution` in a container of `videoAdUiBottomBar`.

I found [this](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/v3/apis?hl=uk#ima.UiElements.COUNTDOWN) as well, but again. Their documentation isn't the best and I can't seem to find anything that tells me how to go about disabling/hiding it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the IMA SDK does not allow you to customize the Ad user interface to use your own countdown timer. You can use their API to disable the countdown timer and attribution but doing more than that might violate their [Ad Serving Guidelines](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3522024?visit_id=636921700531712720-2533278818&rd=1), at least according to [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ima-sdk/WUfKvIMu5Z8/pG0YOYQoCQAJ) on the IMA SDK forum.

Assuming you can get a reference to the `adsRenderingSetting` object, you should be able to remove the countdown and have it show only the Ad Attribution, I believe, as follows (from the same post above):

```
 //DISPLAY COUNTDOWN & AD_ATTRIBUTION
  adsRenderingSettings.uiElements = [google.ima.UiElements.AD_ATTRIBUTION, google.ima.UiElements.COUNTDOWN];

  //DISPLAY  ONLY AD_ATTRIBUTION
  adsRenderingSettings.uiElements = [google.ima.UiElements.AD_ATTRIBUTION];

  //THIS DOES NOTHING - IT'S NOT POSSIBLE TO ONLY SHOW THE COUNTDOWN
  adsRenderingSettings.uiElements = [google.ima.UiElements.COUNTDOWN];
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above solution, if you want to hide both DISPLAY COUNTDOWN & AD_ATTRIBUTION then you can assign an empty array to uiElements.

```
adsRenderingSettings.uiElements = [];
```

According to the IMA SDK documentation, for AdSense/AdX Ads adsRenderingSettings.uiElements are ignored.

You can find this in

```
adsManager.getCurrentAd().getWrapperAdSystems()
```